# Proof of Formula for maximum of binary changes in a two colored chain

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, discrete-optimization

This question possibly could be stated more formal in better mathematical terms but sadly I don't have the knowledge needed for this yet. First we consider a chain of balls of length $n$ (where $n$ is the number of balls and defined to be the "length" of the chain) and where the balls are either black or white. (Specific color doesn't really matter. It is just important that they can have two different colors and each ball only one at the same time.) Now given any random combination of how the balls are colored in the chain. What are the maximum of changes in color one has to perform to get a perfect alternating chain. I conjecture that for a given length $n$ of the chain the maximum number of changes needed to get a perfect alternating (in colors) chain of balls is given by the following function $f$:

$f(n)=\lfloor(n/2)\rfloor$

Sadyl I haven't been able to prove this myself. I have thougth of the chain being a bernoulli chain over some probability space where the colors are either a 50% chance for event B or event A. If someone could say to what topics my question is related or could state it in a more formal way in better mathematical terms I would be very happy. Also if someone has suggestions on how I migth be able to prove this I would be very happy.

Comment: There are only $2$ possible alternating chains:
The one starting with a black ball named $B$, and the one starting with a white ball, named $W$, and these $2$ chains are of opposite colors to one another. 

Assume the number of changes to transform a given chain $C$ to $W$ is $m$.  (we flip $m$ balls to transform $C$ into $W$). Then the number of changes to transform it to $B$ would be $n-m$. (we flip the complementary set). So the smallest number needed to transform it to an alternating chain (either $W$ or $B$), would be $\min(m,n-m)$. The maximum of that value is 
$\lfloor(n/2)\rfloor$

Comment: Thanks a lot. This indeed answered almost everything I wanted to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier to see if you switch the colours of, say, the odd-numbered balls.  Then you want the maximum number of changes needed to get all the balls with the same colour. But that's obvious: either switch all white balls to black, or all black balls to white, whichever there are fewer of.

More formally: suppose your balls are $x_1$ to $x_n$, with, say, $+1$ for black and $-1$ for white.  Let $y_i = (-1)^i x_i$, so $x_i$ alternating corresponds to $y_i$ all black or all white.  If $\sum_i y_i \le 0$, switch
all $y_i$ with $y_i = +1$ to $-1$, if $\sum_i y_i \ge 0$, switch all $-1$ to $+1$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I think you might have misunderstood my question. The balls have to be in an order such that the colors or the signs as you relabeld it are alternating. So for example:

black-white-black-...-white

or

white-black-white-...-black

Not having all balls having the same color. And the start is that the colors are randomly distributed. If I change the color of say a black ball i might have to change the color of a white one too to get the desired color pattern.

Comment: The answer which you have given would be for the question as how many changes does it need to get all balls having the same color in the worst case. The answer to this question is obiviously $f$ as I have defined it. Because considerin that to have a maximum of changes half of the balls has to be colored differently and if not half+/-1 balls are colored differently. From this it follows trivially that the maximum number of changes given by $\lfloor n/2 \rfloor$ as I have defined it.

Comment: @unknownuser Please read my answer again.  The point is that the given problem is equivalent to the problem where you want to get all balls the same colour. You map from one problem to the other by switching the odd-numbered balls.

Comment: Ah yeah sorry. Now I see, what you meant. Sorry for the inconvenience and thanks for your efforts and answer. I thinks this is the most elgant way to solve the problem. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to get an alternating chain. You can have either black-white-black-white-..., or white-black-white-black-... . Suppose it takes $k$ changes to turn the chain into the first option. Then it would take $n-k$ changes to turn the chain into the second option, since you would need to change the opposite set of balls.

For any $k\in \{0,1,\dots,n\}$, the smaller of $k$ and $n-k$ is at most $\lfloor n/2\rfloor$, which implies that $\lfloor n/2\rfloor$ changes always suffice. This is indeed the worst case, which occurs when $\lfloor n/2\rfloor$ balls match the black-white-... pattern, while the remaining $\lceil n/2\rceil$ match the white-black-... pattern. n

Comment: This is essentially the same as Robert Israel's answer.